# How two array extends in single foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extend two array in single foreach loop like ..

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array(1=>'b','2=>c',3=>'d',4=>'e',5=>'f',6=>'g',7=>'x');

foreach($array as first && $aaray2 as second){
  echo first;
  echo second;    
}
```

Is it possible?
how I call indexes of each array and values of each array

Comment: Extend? Do you mean adding more items to both arrays?

Comment: I think here what you need is [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) ?

Comment: What dou mean by extend? You looking for 2D iteration or what?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Since your arrays don't use named keys you can reuse the array key. If you use named keys this only works if the keys are the same.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo $array2[$key];
}
```

You could also use a for loop counting from 0 to the array length since php automatically uses numbers as keys if you don't specify any, but the above solution is probably more readable and will work with named keys.

Comment: What happens if `$array2` has more elements than `$array1` though?

Comment: @Fluffeh: Given his example used the same number of values I'd assume that's not the case. Of course you could expand the solution to check if the target key is present using isset($array2[$key]) and act accordingly.

Comment: It's a good - and ingenious - answer, I wasn't trying to throw mud at it, just thought it might need to be pointed out. +1 from me anyhow :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create one array with key=>value pairs.

```
foreach(array_combine($array, $array2) as $key => $value){

    echo $key;
    echo $value;

}
```

(array_combine returns the combined array, FALSE if the number of elements for each array isn't equal)

Comment: In addition to the equal number restriction, this will only work if all the elements in `$array` are strings or integers. It will not work with objects and such and it will also change the type of floats -- might be important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loops like this:

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
        echo $arr;
        for($i=1; $i<count($array2); $i++){
            echo $array2[$i];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other day I wrote a `ZipIterator` class which is designed to do exactly this.

**Usage example:**

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array('b','c','d','e','f','g','x');

foreach (new ZipIterator($array, $array2) as $pair) {
    echo "first: ".$pair[0].", second: ".$pair[1];
}
```

**Features:**

- Works on all types of [traversables](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), not just arrays
- Works on any number of traversables (not necessarily two)
- Places no restrictions on the values contained in the traversables
- Can be configured to stop when the shortes traversable sequence ends (default behavior), or keep going until all of them are exhausted

**Requirements:**

- PHP 5.4 or later

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/LJs7c2)** and grab [the source](https://gist.github.com/TheDistantSea/6054423) from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array('b','c','d','e','f','g','x');

$mi = new MultipleIterator(
    MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC
);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 'val');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2), 'val2');
foreach($mi as $details) {
    echo $details['val'], ' - ', $details['val2'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

or

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array('b','c','d','e','f','g','x');

$mi = new MultipleIterator(
    MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC
);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 'val');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2), 'val2');
foreach($mi as $details) {
    extract($details);
    echo $val, ' - ', $val2, PHP_EOL;
}
```

or for PHP 5.5+ only

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array('b','c','d','e','f','g','x');

$mi = new MultipleIterator(
    MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC
);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
foreach($mi as list($val, $val2)) {
    echo $val, ' - ', $val2, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just merge two array and do loop

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,);
$array2=array('b','c','d','e','f','g','x');

$array = array_merge($array, $array2);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: He wants to print them in pairs.